# PostgreSQL: INSERT in a sequence and increment all values above the INSERT (make "room" for the INSERT)

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, auto-increment, postgresql-12

I have a table that requires storing my item in a specific position, and the user can "move" the items' positions to "make room" for the new item.

Here is what  the table looks like

```sql
CREATE TABLE   keys (
    key_name   VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    context    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    position   INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ  NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),

    UNIQUE (context, position)
);

INSERT INTO keys (key_name, context, position)
VALUES
('A.1', 'ctx_A', 0), 
('A.2', 'ctx_A', 1), 
('A.3', 'ctx_A', 2), 
('A.4', 'ctx_A', 3),
('B.1', 'ctx_B', 0), 
('B.2', 'ctx_B', 1), 
('B.3', 'ctx_B', 2), 
('B.4', 'ctx_B', 3);
```

I would like to be able to insert a key at position 1 or move the `position` of a (`UNIQUE`) key, and that automatically increments the `position` integer  by 1 for every value greater than the new `INSERT`.

Here is what I have tried so far

```sql
UPDATE keys
SET position = position + 1
WHERE context = 'ctx_A' AND position >= 2;
```

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "keys_context_position_key"
> DETAIL:  Key (context, "position")=(ctx_A, 3) already exists.

But it's not working.

### EDIT

I'm using a Docker image `postgres:12.7`

I found out that using `UNIQUE (context, position) DEFERRABLE` allow me to exec

```sql
UPDATE keys SET position = position + 1 WHERE context = 'ctx_A' AND position > 1;
```

But somthing like

```sql
BEGIN;
  UPDATE keys SET position=2 WHERE context='ctx_A' AND key_name='A.4';
  UPDATE keys SET position=3 WHERE context='ctx_A' AND key_name='A.3';
COMMIT;
```

is still not working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I will answer the question **as asked**, then suggest a couple of improvements as I see it and **then** suggest that you **completely** revise your schema! All the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=60c51f4da34fac940fc6dc3fd53981c9). I have also included a new separate fiddle for a "simplified" framework with no `PRIMARY KEY` update - it makes use of [`GENERATED` columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-generated-columns.html) as a possible simplification strategy - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f0cc60baa3d1c538db1ed3d935ab1891).

### Question as asked:

```
CREATE TABLE   keys 
(
  key_name   VARCHAR(128),

  context    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,

  pos   INTEGER      NOT NULL,  -- changed to "pos" - position is a keyword
                                  -- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-keywords-appendix.html
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ  NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),

  marker TEXT NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT keys_pk PRIMARY KEY (key_name)
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE,

  CONSTRAINT ctxt_pos_uq UNIQUE(context, pos)
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
);
```

A couple of points to note:

- I changed the column named "position" to "pos" because the word 'position' is a [keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-keywords-appendix.html) for PostgreSQL.
- I put in a column called "marker" as a dummy column so I could keep track of my modifications - you may, of course, remove it - but it helps to have a readily identifiable field for testing.

I then populated it as follows:

```
INSERT INTO keys (key_name, context, pos, marker)
VALUES
('A.1', 'ctx_A', 0, 'marker 1 initial'), 
('A.2', 'ctx_A', 1, 'marker 2 initial'), 
('A.3', 'ctx_A', 2, 'marker 3 initial'), 
('A.4', 'ctx_A', 3, 'marker 4 initial'),
('B.1', 'ctx_B', 0, 'marker 5 initial'), 
('B.2', 'ctx_B', 1, 'marker 6 initial'), 
('B.3', 'ctx_B', 2, 'marker 7 initial'), 
('B.4', 'ctx_B', 3, 'marker 8 initial');
```

Then, I ran:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE keys
    SET 
      key_name = 
        LEFT(key_name, STRPOS(key_name, '.')) || ((SPLIT_PART(key_name, '.', 2)::INT + 1))::TEXT,
      context  = 'ctx_A',
      pos = pos + 1
    WHERE LEFT(key_name, STRPOS(key_name, '.')) = 'A.';
  INSERT INTO keys (key_name, context, pos, marker)
    VALUES ('A.1', 'ctx_A_new', 1, 'marker_new');
COMMIT;
```

and then run (check) `SELECT * FROM keys ORDER BY key_name;`.

Result:

```
key_name      context   pos                    created_at   marker
     A.1    ctx_A_new   1   2021-10-28 14:00:46.929092+01   marker_new
     A.2    ctx_A       1   2021-10-28 14:00:46.916923+01   marker 1 initial
     A.3    ctx_A       2   2021-10-28 14:00:46.916923+01   marker 2 initial
     A.4    ctx_A       3   2021-10-28 14:00:46.916923+01   marker 3 initial
     A.5    ctx_A       4   2021-10-28 14:00:46.916923+01   marker 4 initial
     B.1    ctx_B       0   2021-10-28 14:00:46.916923+01   marker 5 initial
     B.2    ctx_B       1   2021-10-28 14:00:46.916923+01   marker 6 initial
     B.3    ctx_B       2   2021-10-28 14:00:46.916923+01   marker 7 initial
     B.4    ctx_B       3   2021-10-28 14:00:46.916923+01   marker 8 initial
```

So, the new record is there and we have "bumped up" the `INTEGER` part of the `key_name` - i.e. the `PRIMARY KEY` has been modified and order has been preserved.

You could also do this - more flexible because the **one thing** SQL doesn't do well is string manipulation - strings are (maybe "were" would be better...) considered as "atomic" and splitting them up and putting them back together is not SQL's *forté*! Having said that, in recent years, there have been **vast** improvements with regular expression libraries and the like.

So, we could, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE   keys_bis 
(
  key_alpha TEXT         NOT NULL, 

  key_num   INTEGER      NOT NULL,
  
  context    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,

  pos   INTEGER      NOT NULL,

  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ  NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  
  marker TEXT NOT NULL,  -- this is for tracing purposes

  -- It's up to you to ensure that the key_name field is valid!

  CONSTRAINT keys_bis_pk PRIMARY KEY (key_alpha, key_num)
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE,

  CONSTRAINT ctxt_pos_bis_uq UNIQUE(context, pos)
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
);
```

and populate it:

```
INSERT INTO keys_bis (key_alpha, key_num, context, pos, marker)
VALUES
('A.', 1, 'ctx_A', 0, 'marker 1 initial'), 
('A.', 2, 'ctx_A', 1, 'marker 2 initial'), 
('A.', 3, 'ctx_A', 2, 'marker 3 initial'), 
('A.', 4, 'ctx_A', 3, 'marker 4 initial'),
('B.', 1, 'ctx_B', 0, 'marker 5 initial'), 
('B.', 2, 'ctx_B', 1, 'marker 6 initial'), 
('B.', 3, 'ctx_B', 2, 'marker 7 initial'), 
('B.', 4, 'ctx_B', 3, 'marker 8 initial');
```

And check with `SELECT * FROM keys_bis;` - result:

```
key_alpha   key_num context pos                   created_at        marker
       A.         1   ctx_A   0 2021-10-28 14:31:04.126172+01   marker 1 initial
       A.         2   ctx_A   1 2021-10-28 14:31:04.126172+01   marker 2 initial
       A.         3   ctx_A   2 2021-10-28 14:31:04.126172+01   marker 3 initial
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

Then we run the update:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE keys_bis 
    SET 
      key_num = key_num + 1,
      context = 'ctx_A',
      pos   = pos + 1
    WHERE key_alpha = 'A.';
  INSERT INTO keys_bis (key_alpha, key_num, context, pos, marker)
  VALUES ('A.', 1, 'ctx_A_new', 1, 'marker_new');
COMMIT;
```

This runs successfully - and we check - `SELECT * FROM keys_bis ORDER BY key_alpha, key_num;` - result:

```
key_alpha   key_num   context   pos                    created_at       marker
       A.         1 ctx_A_new   1   2021-10-28 14:42:39.161205+01   marker_new
       A.         2 ctx_A       1   2021-10-28 14:42:39.148996+01   marker 1 initial
       A.         3 ctx_A       2   2021-10-28 14:42:39.148996+01   marker 2 initial
       A.         4 ctx_A       3   2021-10-28 14:42:39.148996+01   marker 3 initial
       A.         5 ctx_A       4   2021-10-28 14:42:39.148996+01   marker 4 initial
       B.         1 ctx_B       0   2021-10-28 14:42:39.148996+01   marker 5 initial
       B.         2 ctx_B       1   2021-10-28 14:42:39.148996+01   marker 6 initial
       B.         3 ctx_B       2   2021-10-28 14:42:39.148996+01   marker 7 initial
       B.         4 ctx_B       3   2021-10-28 14:42:39.148996+01   marker 8 initial
```

So, we can see that the `INTEGER` part of the `PRIMARY KEY` has been incremented and  "bumped up"  - we can see, for example, that `"marker 4 initial"` now has `5` as the numeric part of the `PRIMARY KEY`.

### Schema change:

You really need to revise your schema - put in an `INTEGER` surrogate key. Updating parts of a `PRIMARY KEY` has a ["bad code smell"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) about it - you can see this in the contortions that have to be gone through to update the `PK`. I would **strongly suggest** that even **if** the `PK` were easier to `UPDATE`, it's not something you should be doing on a regular basis - if it's a one-off integrating with another system, fine, but day-to-day - you need to search for another solution!

I know that you **may** be in a situation where `I have to interface with a legacy system` or `I'm only the consultant and not allowed to make changes...`.

Why don't you use `context` and `pos` as the `PK`? Both are already `NOT NULL` and both together are `UNIQUE` - therefore good candidates for a `PK`!

Here are a couple of pieces of code that may help if you want to/can change the table. You can either create a new column and `UPDATE` or `INSERT` into a new table using some/all of the functions below (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29896899/470530) and see bottom of [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=60c51f4da34fac940fc6dc3fd53981c9)):

```
--
-- A few ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51193857/470530
--

WITH test AS
(
  SELECT 'AASDFSD.435434' AS v
  UNION ALL SELECT 'SDXVZ.343534'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'AEE#3434$%$^%^&^&^&^&AAL.12345'
)
SELECT
  v,
  RIGHT(v, LENGTH(v) - STRPOS(v, '.')),
  SUBSTRING(v FROM '^[A-Z]+[\.]'),  -- will pick AA., BBB., CCSXDEER., 
  SUBSTRING(v FROM '\d+$'),
  (select (regexp_matches(v, '[^A,]+', 'g'))[1] offset 0 limit 1) as c1
FROM
  test;
```

Result:

```
             v  right   substring   substring   c1
AASDFSD.435434  435434  AASDFSD.    435434  SDFSD.435434
SDXVZ.343534    343534  SDXVZ.  343534  SDXVZ.343534
AEE#3434$%$^%^&^&^&^&AAL.12345  12345       12345   EE#3434$%$^%^&^&^&^&
```

You're better off avoiding [regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-matching.html) if possible - they are resource intensive!

### Why this is a nightmare!

To perform an `UPDATE` in the middle of the table, you have to manually keep track of all of the previous `UPDATE`s so you know which parts of the `PK` to `UPDATE` - as follows:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE keys_bis 
    SET 
      key_num = key_num + 1,
      context = 'ctx_A',
      pos   = pos + 1
    WHERE (key_alpha = 'A.' AND pos >= 2);
  INSERT INTO keys_bis (key_alpha, key_num, context, pos, marker)
  VALUES ('A.', 3, 'ctx_A_new_3', 3, 'marker_new_3');
COMMIT;
```

See fiddle for result (at bottom).

It will work, as long as you remember to set:

```
WHERE (key_alpha = 'A.' AND pos >= 2);
```

and

```
VALUES ('A.', 3, 'ctx_A_new_3', 3, 'marker_new_3');
```

The `pos` value in the `UPDATE` clause to 1 less than the new value of `pos` in the `WHERE` clause! A good candidate for a function therefore? You have a function in your own answer,but you're doing this manually here:

```
 WHERE key_name IN ('A.3', 'A.4');
```

If you're going to use a function, then at least set it in the parameters to the function. What happens if you have 500 values (or 5,000 or...)?

### A simplification:

I did a separate fiddle for this part - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f0cc60baa3d1c538db1ed3d935ab1891).

I reread the question and noticed that it wasn't in fact the `PK` that required `UPDATE`ing - it was the `UNIQUE` constraint - the principles however are very similar. For the purposes of a complete explanation of how I would go about this, and making use of an **extremely** useful feature of all of the major RDBMSs - that is [`GENERATED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-generated-columns.html) fields/columns! `GENERATED` is the [SQL Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_column) name.

These also go by the name `COMPUTED`, `CALCULATED`, `PERSISTED`, `DERIVED` or even `VIRTUAL` - although the `VIRTUAL` (best avoided) keyword is also (confusingly) used for the storage class of the column (`STORED` or `VIRTUAL`) - the first meaning that the value is actually stored on disk and the second meaning that it's calculated on the fly. As of the time of writing (28/10/2021), PostgreSQL [doesn't support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-generated-columns.html) `VIRTUAL` columns.

I created a new table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE   keys_ter 
(
  key_name   VARCHAR(128),
  context    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  pos   INTEGER      NOT NULL,  
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ  NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  marker TEXT NOT NULL,

  key_alpha TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (LEFT(key_name, STRPOS(key_name, '.'))) STORED,

  key_num   INT  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SPLIT_PART(key_name, '.', 2)::INT) STORED,

  CONSTRAINT keys_ter_pk PRIMARY KEY (key_name)
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE,

  CONSTRAINT ter_ctxt_pos_uq UNIQUE(context, pos)
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
);
```

Populate as for the original keys table - then `SELECT * FROM keys_ter ORDER BY key_alpha, key_num;` - result:

```
key_name    context pos                   created_at    marker  key_alpha    
    key_num
     A.1      ctx_A   0 2021-10-28 17:02:17.48598+01    marker 1 initial    A.  1
     A.2      ctx_A   1 2021-10-28 17:02:17.48598+01    marker 2 initial    A.  2
     A.3      ctx_A   2 2021-10-28 17:02:17.48598+01    marker 3 initial    A.  3
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

We can see the `GENERATED` fields  - this makes things slightly easier when `UPDATING` if we happen to know the `INTEGER` part of the `PK` as follows:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  -- INSERTING new record between pos at 2 new record - pos = 2
  UPDATE keys_ter
    SET 
      pos = pos + 1
  WHERE key_num > 2 AND context = 'ctx_A';              -- we know the key_num = 2!
  INSERT INTO keys_ter (key_name, context, pos, marker)
    VALUES('A.43', 'ctx_A', 2, 'marker_new_A.43');
COMMIT;
```

Update successful - we check `SELECT * FROM keys_ter ORDER BY context, pos;` - result:

```
    key_name    context pos                   created_at    marker   
   key_alpha    key_num
         A.1      ctx_A   0 2021-10-28 17:02:17.48598+01    marker 1 initial    A.  1
         A.2      ctx_A   1 2021-10-28 17:02:17.48598+01    marker 2 initial    A.  2
        A.43      ctx_A   2 2021-10-28 17:02:17.499004+01   marker_new_A.43 A.  43
         A.3      ctx_A   3 2021-10-28 17:02:17.48598+01    marker 3 initial    A.  3
         A.4      ctx_A   4 2021-10-28 17:02:17.48598+01    marker 4 initial    A.  4
         B.1      ctx_B   0 2021-10-28 17:02:17.48598+01    marker 5 initial    B.  1
    ...
    ... snipped for brevity
    ...
```

This can be "handy" and make life a bit easier under certain circumstances - just a thought. À+ et +1 pour un question intéressante qui m'a fait réflechir!

Comment: Hello, thanks you for this amazing answer, i've learned a lot ! this is a small piece of code to explain my issue, `keys` are the parent table of `keys_values` linked with a `key_name` and the keys aren't `A.1`, `A.2` ... but full words separated by dot, i used `A.1` for explain and simple purpose

Comment: @albttx - welcome to the forum! I've added some code at the bottom (and corrected a typo - see edits). Your method uses `WHERE key_name IN ('A.3', 'A.4');` where you list the values above the value you're inserting! What happens if you've 50 more (or 500 or 5,000...)? You should pass the value in as a parameter and do 1 less than that in the UPDATE - `pos >= 2` for an `INSERT` at `pos`  = 3. HTH!

Comment: @albttx - I added a couple of bits at the end using `GENERATED` columns for this - you might be interested?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution

here is a sql script that show how it's work

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS keys;

CREATE TABLE   keys (
    key_name   VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

    context    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,

    position   INTEGER      NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ  NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),

    UNIQUE (context, position) DEFERRABLE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION glide_keys_position()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE keys
    SET position = position + 1
    WHERE
        context = NEW.context AND position >= NEW.position;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_glide_keys_position
BEFORE INSERT ON keys
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE glide_keys_position();


-- here a sample of data
INSERT INTO keys (key_name, context, position)
VALUES
('A.1', 'ctx_A', 0), 
('A.2', 'ctx_A', 1), 
('A.3', 'ctx_A', 2), 
('A.4', 'ctx_A', 3),
('B.1', 'ctx_B', 0), 
('B.2', 'ctx_B', 1), 
('B.3', 'ctx_B', 2), 
('B.4', 'ctx_B', 3);

-- UPDATE keys SET position = position + 1 WHERE context = 'ctx_A' AND position > 1;

INSERT INTO keys (key_name, context, position) VALUES ('A.10', 'ctx_A', 2);

BEGIN;
  SET CONSTRAINTS keys_context_position_key DEFERRED;

  UPDATE keys
  SET position = CASE key_name
    WHEN 'A.4' THEN (SELECT position FROM keys WHERE context='ctx_A' AND key_name = 'A.3')
    WHEN 'A.3' THEN (SELECT position FROM keys WHERE context='ctx_A' AND key_name = 'A.4')
  END
  WHERE key_name IN ('A.3', 'A.4');
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM keys WHERE context='ctx_A' ORDER BY position;
```

OUTPUT:

```
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE TRIGGER
INSERT 0 8
INSERT 0 1
BEGIN
SET CONSTRAINTS
UPDATE 2
COMMIT
 key_name | context | position |          created_at
----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------
 A.1      | ctx_A   |        0 | 2021-10-28 11:09:44.667153+00
 A.2      | ctx_A   |        1 | 2021-10-28 11:09:44.667153+00
 A.10     | ctx_A   |        2 | 2021-10-28 11:09:44.669278+00
 A.4      | ctx_A   |        3 | 2021-10-28 11:09:44.667153+00
 A.3      | ctx_A   |        4 | 2021-10-28 11:09:44.667153+00
(5 rows)
```

ps: i put it in a [public github gist](https://gist.github.com/albttx/6c77a9e52befffa4a0ced52055e06b97)